# How can i login users from a jwt token and set roles .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2

I have managed to decode the jwt token and created a principal but when i use the HttpContext.SignInUserAsync no user is logged in

```
      public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
       {

           if (Data.accessToken == null)
           {

               var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "access_token");
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("signin", "Authentication");
               }

               Data.accessToken = token;

               var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
               var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(Data.accessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;


               if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
               {



                   var claims = new List<Claim>
                       {
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, tokenS.Claims.ElementAt(1).Value),
                           new Claim("FullName", tokenS.Claims.ElementAt(1).Value),
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                       };

                   Data.EMAIL = tokenS.Claims.ElementAt(1).Value;

                   var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                       claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);



                   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });


                   return Redirect("/");


               }

           }
           return View();
       }
```

I expect the user decoded from the jwt token to be set as the signed in user and the role admin passed in to be used for authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to read the token manually like that.. Net Core magically does that for you. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in a controller for example will get you the valid, logged in user provided you have configured everything else correctly.

I am making the assumption that you have set the controller to use the attribute [Authorize] attribute and enabled the Authorization stuff in the IServiceCollection configuration?

Comment: yes i have configured the authorization. Also do i need to do servives.AddIdentity<>() ? or perhaps share the necessary configurations that should be there ?